# Integrate vector norm over rectangle

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

I need to integrate the function $f(x,y) = \left\|\left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} \right)\right\|  = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ over a rectangular domain $[x_1,x_2] \times [y_1,y_2]$.

I.e., I need $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \int_{y_1}^{y_2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \, dy \, dx$$

The origin may or may not be inside the rectangle.

Is there an analytical way of calculating this integral? I haven't been able to work out the primitive, and converting to polar form gives me a domain that I can't work with.

If there is no analytical answer, what would be a fast numerical algorithm?

Comment: To perform the inside integrand, let $y = x\sinh t$.

Comment: I don't think that one can express the outer integral in terms of elementary functions, however.

Comment: This wikipedia page lists the needed integrals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_inverse_hyperbolic_functions

Comment: It's probably easier to integrate numerically

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I've decided to integrate numerically, just like Dylan suggest.